# Return sum(column) == 0 rows in join and group by query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE transaction_tbl (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    date TEXT NOT NULL,
    category INTEGER NOT NULL,
    amount REAL NOT NULL,  
    FOREIGN KEY(category) REFERENCES category_tbl(_id)
);
```

I want to be able to select on category, and group by week (based on `date`), and include weeks where no transactions were made for that category.

With the following, I can see that that relevant weeks exist for *some* transaction under any category:

```
sqlite> select distinct strftime('%Y/%W',replace(date,'/','-')) as span from transaction_tbl;
span
<snip>
2020/37
2020/38
2020/39
2020/40
2020/41
<snip>
```

But, when using that as a ephemeral table to left join on, week '2020/39' doesn't show:

```
sqlite> with spans as (select distinct strftime('%Y/%W',replace(date,'/','-')) as span from transaction_tbl)  select span, category, sum(coalesce(amount, 0)) as sum from spans left join transaction_tbl tt on span=strftime('%Y/%W',replace(date,'/','-')) where category in (13) group by span, category;
span|category|sum
<snip>
2020/37|13|XXX
2020/38|13|XXX
               <-- This '2020/29|13|0' row should appear but does not
2020/40|13|XXX
2020/41|13|XXX
<snip>
```

Just one example, my .sqlite_history file has quite a few not working examples...

Based on a few other SO questions if found, it looks like empty rows in the right table of a left join, including ephemeral tables *should* be included but it doesn't appear to be working for me. for reasons I can't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your query you are not doing any aggregation.
I assume that you want `sum(amount)` and not just `amount`.
Also, you must set the condition `tt.category in (13)` or just `tt.category = 13` in the `ON` clause and remove the `WHERE` clause, because that `WHERE` clause removes all unmatched rows and turns the join to an `INNER` join:

```
with spans as (
  select distinct strftime('%Y/%W',replace(date,'/','-')) as span 
  from transaction_tbl
)  
select s.span, tt.category, coalesce(sum(tt.amount), 0) as sum 
from spans s left join transaction_tbl tt 
on ss.span = strftime('%Y/%W', replace(tt.date, '/' , '-')) and tt.category in (13) 
group by s.span, tt.category;
```

Comment: Yep, of course the sum should include `sum(...)`, and yes, moving the category select to the join works - It gives `2020/39||0`, which is close enough I can work with it I reckon. Cheers.